# How to get my desired view result from one table

Tags: sql, sql-server, view

I have a table (mytable) like the example below that consists of items that any collection has:

```
CollCode | ItemCode
---------+---------
   101   |   201
   101   |   202
   101   |   203
   202   |   204
   202   |   205
```

And I want to get back a view from this table that results in sth like this :

```
CollCode | ItemCode
---------+----------
   101   |   201
   101   |   202
   101   |   203
   101   |   204
   101   |   205
   202   |   204
   202   |   205
```

It means that I want all of the items of a collection of all levels not just first level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are looking for a recursive CTE.  Try this:

```
with t(CollCode, ItemCode) as (
       values (101, 201), (101, 202), (101, 203),
              (202, 204), (202, 205)
      ),
      cte as (
       select t.CollCode, t.ItemCode
       from t
       union all
       select cte.CollCode, t.ItemCode
       from cte join
            t
            on t.collCode = cte.ItemCode
      )
select *
from cte
order by collCode;
```

(Obviously, the CTE `t` is just to provide sample data to demonstrate that this works.)

EDIT:

To remove intermediate results:

```
select *
from cte
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.collCode = cte.ItemCode)
order by collCode;
```

Comment: I am a little confused. would please give me the code of creation of my desired view as explained.

Comment: @AAAE_N just add "create view my_view_name as" before the SQL and you are done.

Comment: @arturro what about the t table with sample data in the above code. My table has more than one thousand records.

Comment: @AAAE_N just replace t with your table and remove it from the sql: create view my_view as with 
      cte as (
       select CollCode, ItemCode
       from my_table 
       union all
       select cte.CollCode, my_table.ItemCode
       from cte join
            my_table
            on my_table.collCode = cte.ItemCode
      )
select *
from cte
order by collCode;

Comment: Thanks @arturro and also Gordon Linoff

Comment: @Gordon Linoff what if I want to remove intermediate items of a collection means remove this row (101 , 202) from my taken view.

Comment: @arturro  what if I want to remove intermediate items of a collection means remove this row (101 , 202) from my taken view

Comment: @AAAE_N . . . Normally, my response would be to ask question as *questions* but not comments.  That is just a slight modification of the query, so I added it to the answer.